# Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: Compilation failed: range out of order in character class

Tags: php, preg-split

I am trying to convert an string into array by preg_split function. I want to get an array with 1 letter and optional number. For xample, if i have "NH2O3", i want the this output:

```
[0] => N,
[1] => H2,
[2] => O3
```

I have this code:

```
$formula = "NH2O3";
$pattern = '/[a-Z]{1}[0-9]?/';
$formula = preg_split($pattern, $formula);
```

But this retrieve an error:

> Warning: preg_split() [function.preg-split]: Compilation failed: range
>   out of order in character class at offset 3 in
>   /home/masqueci/public_html/wp-content/themes/Flatnews/functions.php on
>   line 865 bool(false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[a-Z]` doesn't mean anything, if you want uppercase and lowercase letters, two solutions:

```
$pattern = '/[a-z][0-9]?/i';
```

or

```
$pattern = '/[a-zA-Z][0-9]?/';
```

Inside a character class `-` is used to define a range of characters in the [unicode table](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF). Since `Z` is before `a` in the table, the range doesn't exist.

Note: using `[A-z]` is false too, because there are other characters than letters between `Z` and `a`

A pattern to do that:

```
$formula = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z][a-z]?\d*)/', 'HgNO3', null, 1);
```

where `(?=..)` is a lookahead and means "followed by"

And 1 is a shortcut for PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY

Comment: This will fix the error, but wouldn't still give the required result.

Comment: It is better to use the named constant instead of their int value, for readability.

Answer (score 2):

The error is due to `a-Z` (lowercase + uppercase). Change that to `a-zA-Z` or use the modifier `i` for case-insensitive matching, e.g.

```
/[a-z]{1}[0-9]?/i
```

You also need to use preg_split a bit differently in order to get that result:

```
$formula = "NH2O3";
$pattern = '/([a-z][0-9]?)/i';
$formula = preg_split($pattern, $formula, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Specifics from http://php.net/preg_split:

> PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY If this flag is set, only non-empty pieces will be
>   returned by preg_split().
>
> PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE If this flag is set, parenthesized expression
>   in the delimiter pattern will be captured and returned as well.